# Get an attribute of an instance with a decorator

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, decorator

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Dumb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "beautiful attribute"

    def do_something(self):
        print("awesome method")
```

I know that I can get the value of the attribute `x` by using `getattr(obj,"x")` and I know that I can get a reference to the object from a method using `method.__self__`, like this:

```
duh = Dumb()
getattr(duh,"x")
object = duh.do_something.__self__
getattr(object,"x")
```

I'm using [repl.it](http://repl.it) to show some snippets to a friend. It's convenient since it executes the script in the browser, but I can't use `pdb` for debugging. So, I thought I could use a decorator to obtain some info about the attributes of the object when one of his methods is executed:

```
def info(attribute):
    def wrap_gen(func):
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs)
            object = func.__self__
            value = getattr(object,attribute)
            func(*args,**kwargs)
            print("The attribute %s is %s"%(attribute,value))
        return wrapper
   return wrap_gen
```

And then use it to decorate `do_something` in `Dumb`. However, it doesn't work,since it raises the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

If I understand this correctly, it's because when the decorator... decorates the method, there is no istance of `Dumb` (there is no class at all) and so, the method doesn't have any reference to that.

How can I accomplish such a task? A possible workaround could be write and test the snippet on my computer (so I can debug it properly), and then copy&paste the snippet, but it's a little bit cumbersome.

EDIT:
I finally found what I was looking for, it's even simpler then what I tried:

[Python decorator accessing class arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195795/python-decorator-with-arguments-and-accessing-class-instance?rq=1)

Basically, I have to explicitly pass `self` as an argument to the wrapper of the function, and then use it as a reference:

```
def info(attribute):
        def wrap_gen(func):
            def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs)
                value = getattr(self,attribute)
                func(self,*args,**kwargs)
                print("The attribute %s is %s"%(attribute,value))
            return wrapper
       return wrap_gen
```