# Am I using Decorators correctly?

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decorator

I am unsure of how to use Decorators properly; I have drawn reference from [Real Python](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) and [Try-Except for Multiple Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024966/try-except-every-method-in-class). I am coding up a Linear Regression class, and I realised that you need to call `fit` before you can do predict, or other methods that my class have. But it is cumbersome to define each and every method to raise error when the `self._fitted` flag is `False`. So I turned to decorators, I am unsure if I am using correctly, because it does behave the way I want it to, however it neglects any other forms of errors like ValueError etc. Asking for advice here.

```
import functools
from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError


def NotFitted(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            raise NotFittedError

    return wrapper

class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self, fit_intercept: bool = True):
        self.coef_ = None
        self.intercept_ = None
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        # a flag to turn to true once we called fit on the data
        self._fitted = False

def check_shape(self, X: np.array, y: np.array):
    # if X is 1D array, then it is simple linear regression, reshape to 2D
    # [1,2,3] -> [[1],[2],[3]] to fit the data
    if X is not None and len(X.shape) == 1:
        X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
    # self._features = X
    # self.intercept_ = y
    return X, y

def fit(self, X: np.array = None, y: np.array = None):
    X, y = self.check_shape(X, y)
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape[0], X.shape[1]
    if self.fit_intercept:
   
        X = np.c_[np.ones(n_samples), X]
    XtX = np.dot(X.T, X)
    XtX_inv = np.linalg.inv(XtX)
    XtX_inv_Xt = np.dot(XtX_inv, X.T)
    _optimal_betas = np.dot(XtX_inv_Xt, y)

    # set attributes from None to the optimal ones
    self.coef_ = _optimal_betas[1:]
    self.intercept_ = _optimal_betas[0]
    self._fitted = True

    return self

@NotFitted
def predict(self, X: np.array):
    """
    after calling .fit, you can continue to .predict to get model prediction
    """
    # if self._fitted is False:
    #     raise NotFittedError
    if self.fit_intercept:
        y_hat = self.intercept_ + np.dot(X, self.coef_)
    else:
        y_hat = self.intercept_
    return y_hat
```

Comment: If your problem with this approach is that the errors from the wrapped `func` are not propagated, you can change your error handling in the decorator to rethrow the error instead of always using a `NotFittedError`. But I am confused: does your decorator even have any effect other than catching those errors and masking them as `NotFittedError`? I don't think `_fitted` is ever read?

Comment: Yes that is probably what I wanted to ask, do I need to call `_fitted` in the decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quickly repeat what you want to do, to make sure I'm not misunderstanding that.
You would like to have a decorator `@NotFitted` such that every function you annotate with it will first check whether `self._fitted` is `True` and fail with a `NotFittedError` if it is `False` instead of executing the function.

By looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196410/2550406) you can get an understanding for how you could pass additional arguments to the decorator.
I'm not used to using decorators, so I had to quickly test this to see what's going on there in your code - why you don't need a parameter `self` for the `def wrapper`:

```py
>>> def deco1(func):
...   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...     print("Args are {}".format(args))
...   return wrapper

>>> class Foo(object):
...   @deco1
...   def meth(self, a):
...     print("a: "+a)

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.meth("hello")
Args are (<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f37676a4128>, 'hello')
```

As you can see here, the first argument the `wrapper` prints is actually the `self`. `*args` simply collects all non-keyword arguments into a tuple, including `self`, which is the very first argument here. We could be more explicit by doing `def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` instead if we wanted to (see that linked question).

> Do I need to call `_fitted` in the decorator?

Yes, because `self._fitted` is how you keep track of whether it is already fitted or not. You can access it through the first element of `*args` by doing `args[0]._fitted`. But I would prefer explicitly passing taking self. Either way, you can check inside the `wrapper` whether `self._fitted` is `True`, and fail if it is not. So I define this example:

```py
#!/bin/env/python3
# Declaring my own NotFittedError, because I don't want to
# from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
# just for this small example.

class NotFittedError (Exception):
    pass

def NotFitted ( foo ):
    def wrapper ( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        if not self._fitted:
            raise NotFittedError()
        else:
            foo ( self, *args, **kwargs )

    return wrapper

class Foo() :
    # Set self._fitted to false just to be explicit.
    # The initial value should be False anyway.
    def __init__(self):
        self._fitted = False

    def fit(self):
        self._fitted = True

    @NotFitted
    def predict(self, X):
        # code here that assumes fit was already called
        print ( "Successfully Predicted!" )
```

And now we can use it. In the following snippet, I imported it as `tmp` because I had it in a file called `tmp.py`. You won't have to do that since you have it all in the same file.

```py
>>> import tmp
>>> f = tmp.Foo()
>>> f.predict("a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/generic/Downloads/tmp.py", line 12, in wrapper
    raise NotFittedError()
tmp.NotFittedError
>>> f.fit()
>>> f.predict("a")
Successfully Predicted!
```

---

A few further comments:

- If your only goal is to raise a `NotFittedError`, maybe you wouldn't need to do any of this. The [sklearn.NotFittedError](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError.html) would be raised anyway, I think.
- If you want to distinguish between different kinds of errors in that case, it could also be useful for you to know that [you can have multiple `except` clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095782/2550406)